# Can't update var value with text field value. Swift

Tags: swift

I am creating an app for a project that determines whether or not a year is a leap year or not.

The overall logic itself is very simple, however I am trying to make it so when the button is pressed, it will take the value within the text field and then update var year with that value.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var guessLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var guessTextField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func logic() {
        // var year = guessTextField This is where the issue is.
        var value1 = (year % 4)
        var value2 = (year % 100)
        var value3 = (year % 400)
        var criteria: Bool!
        print (value1)
        print (value2)
        criteria = false
        func yearChecker() {
            if value1 == 0 {
                criteria = true
            }
            if value2 != 0, value1 == 0 {
                criteria = true
            }
            if value3 == 0, value1 == 0 {
                criteria = true
            }
            if criteria == true {
                leapYearAlert()
            }
            if criteria == false {
                showBoundsAlert()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var year = guessTextField.text
        logic()
    }
    
    func showBoundsAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry, The Year You Chose is Not Special", message: "You're Year is Not a Leap Year:(", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func leapYearAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController( title: "Your Year is Special!", message: "The Year You Chose is in Fact a Leap Year!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Check For Another Year?", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast `year` as `Int` because `guessTextField.text` return `String`.

```
@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    logic()
}
```

Change `value1`, `value2`, `value3` from `var` to `let` as they don't change.

```
func logic() {
    let year: Int = Int(guessTextField.text ?? "0")!
    let value1: Int = (year % 4)
    let value2: Int = (year % 100)
    let value3: Int = (year % 400)
    var criteria: Bool = false
    print (value1)
    print (value2)
    
    if value1 == 0 {
        criteria = true
    }
    if value2 != 0, value1 == 0 {
        criteria = true
    }
    if value3 == 0, value1 == 0 {
        criteria = true
    }
    
    if criteria == true {
        leapYearAlert()
    } else {
        showBoundsAlert()
    }
}
```

Comment: I pasted that code inside my view controller, however now I am getting a similar issue to one which I got in the past. "Value of type 'String?' must be unwrapped to be a value of type 'String'.  

" Coalesce using ?? to provide a default when the optional value contains nil

force-unwrap using ! to abort execution if the options value contains nil

Comment: I have updated my answer. Change ```let year: Int = Int(guessTextField.text) ?? 0``` to ```let year: Int = Int(guessTextField.text ?? "0") ?? 0```

Comment: I have also modified the ```logic()``` method.

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed every issue and the app works perfectly now!